# Get the flatten index of a multi-dimension array from its shape and a coordinate

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

Having the shape of a multi-dimension array, I would like to convert a coordinate into an flatten index.

Note: such array may have more than 2 dimensions.

**Example 1:** In the following 2-dimension array having the shape [3, 3]:

```
[
  [ nil, nil, nil ],
  [ "*", nil, nil ],
  [ nil, nil, nil ]
]
```

the coordinate of `*` is [1, 0], and:

```
coordinates_to_index([3, 3], [1, 0]) # => 3
```

**Example 2:** In the following 3-dimension array having the shape [3, 3, 2]:

```
[
  [
    [ nil, nil, nil ],
    [ "*", nil, nil ],
    [ nil, nil, nil ]
  ],
  [
    [ nil, nil, nil ],
    [ nil, nil, nil ],
    [ nil, nil, nil ]
  ]
]
```

the coordinate of `*` is now [0, 1, 0], and:

```
coordinates_to_index([3, 3, 2], [0, 1, 0]) # => 3
```

How should we compute this with Ruby?  I would like a method such as `coordinates_to_index(shape, coordinates)`.  Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did it this way:

```
def coordinates2index(shape, *coordinates)
  (shape[1..-1]+[1]).zip(coordinates).map{|a|a.reduce(:*)}.reduce(:+)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of rows does not matter; you only need the number of columns, which is `3`.

- To convert a coordinate `[1, 0]` to a flattened index:

  ```
  3 * 1 + 0 # => 3
  ```
- To convert a flattened index `3` to a coordinate:

  ```
  3.divmod(3) # => [1, 0]
  ```

Comment: In my country, elementary school students solve these kinds of problems.

Comment: Appreciate your help, @sawa. Have you got a general solution for more than 2 dimensions? Thanks! (I added an example in my question)